# CyberArk Manuals or Guides

Tags: cyber-ark

Can anyone kindly help me locate PDF or MS Word copies of the manuals or guides following in the public: a) CyberArk  Application  Identity Manager b) CyberArk Credentials Manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

the vendor is extremely secretively not to disclose any information related to how the product work. I think the vendor also take great effort to remove any public disclosure of the documentation. Binding by the document restriction

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I was able to register on cyberark.com, and get documentation about a specific Cyberark feature that I needed at the time. It was via their paid support channel (was an enterprise customer at the time) and  the support people sent me PDF documents via secured download from their site.

So my suggestion is to register on cyberark.com for their support (assuming your company is already licensed for cyberark products).

Comment: Many thanks, I appreciate your answer; I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

All publicly available documentation about CyberArk products can be found on [CyberArk docs](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/Portal/Docs.html). Since version 10.x, all official documentation about the individual components are published there.

Answer (score 0):

you can find all the documentation for all the products in the cyber-ark website.
or in the support vault where the PDFs for all versions are stored and ready to be downloaded...

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate portals offered by CyberArk.
[This portal](https://www.cyberark.com/product-security) https://www.cyberark.com/product-security/  is where the latest security bulletins are posted. To access you will need login to [their Technical Community](https://cyberark-customers.force.com/s/login/)
https://cyberark-customers.force.com/s/login/   You can register in this portal as a customer or partner.

The [other portal is the Support Portal](https://support.cyberark.com) https://support.cyberark.com which will require an active Support contract with CyberArk. You can download product specific patches, tools etc from this site. This portal login is only for a select set of users who are authorized to download product specific artifacts

Comment: Sorry all of the links ask me to sign in. I just spent a few hours with their documentation and had not to create an account and log in anywhere, thus I'm voting for the other answer which links to the public cyberark docs site.